# 'NoneType' Error While WebScraping StockTwits

Tags: python, web-scraping, stocktwits

I am trying to write a script that simply reads and prints all of the tickers on a particular accounts watchlist. I have managed to navigate to the page print the user's name from the HTML, and now I want to print all the tickers he follows by using find() to find their  location, then .find_all() to find each ticker, but every time I try to use the find() command to navigate to the watchlist tickers it returns 'NoneType.'

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlwt import Workbook
import xlrd
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hisPage = ("https://stocktwits.com/GregRieben/watchlist")

page = urllib2.urlopen(hisPage)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

his_name = soup.find("span", {"class":"st_33aunZ3 st_31YdEUQ st_8u0ePN3 st_2mehCkH"})

name = his_name.text.strip()
print(name)

watchlist = soup.find("div", {"class":"st_16989tz"})

tickers = watchlist.find_all('span', {"class":"st_1QzH2P8"})

print(type(watchlist))
print(len(watchlist))
```

Here I want the highlighted value (LSPD.CA) and all the others afterwards (they all have the exact same HTML set up)

[image: highlighted value]

Here is my Error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That content is dynamically added from an api call (so not present in your request to original url where DOM is not updated as it would be when using a browser). You can find the API call for the watchlist in the network traffic. It returns json. You can extract what you want from that.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/watchlists/user/396907.json').json()
tickers = [i['symbol'] for i in r['watchlist']['symbols']]
print(tickers)
```

---

If you need to get user id to pass to API it is present in a number of places in response from your original url. I am using regex to grab from a script tag

```
import requests, re

p = re.compile(r'subjectUser":{"id":(\d+)')

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://stocktwits.com/GregRieben/watchlist')
    user_id = p.findall(r.text)[0]
    r = s.get('https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/watchlists/user/' + user_id + '.json').json()
    tickers = [i['symbol'] for i in r['watchlist']['symbols']]
print(tickers)
```

Comment: Is the only way to get it through json?

Comment: It's the easy way. All the tickers are there. More expensive overhead would be to use browser automation such as selenium,

Comment: Is there a way to access that six digit number at the end anywhere else in the HTML somehow? Trying to make this work for a small list of people.

Comment: ids = [i['id'] for i in r['watchlist']['symbols']]    they are present in the json. Assuming that is what you meant.

Comment: Thank you, lastly what is the [i['id'] for i... form you are using. obviously it is a for loop but how can I learn how to use this type of form

Comment: Also, I was talking about the 396907 username/number in the url. How would i be able to get that # somewhere else if possible.